# google-cast-sdk audio and subtitles manual handling on sender and receiver

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

we occurred an issue handling manually audio track and subtitles on sender web and mobile (v3 for both).
Basically, we are able to add some track info before load media, we found the added tracks on the receiver but there are present also the tracks that come from the manifest in two formats (AF and standard object).

There is a way to handle them once and to remove the original that comes from manifest on the receiver side?

Additionally, in this way, the senders will be notified of the change (eg. visible only audio track manually added)?

Many thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use message interception:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_features#message-interception

Your interceptor should return the modified request or a Promise that resolves with the modified request value.

You can add your own tracks:

```
request.media.contentId = mediaUrl;
      request.media.contentType = 'application/dash+xml';
      request.media.tracks = [{
        trackId: 1,
        trackContentId: captionUrl,
        trackContentType: 'text/vtt',
        type: cast.framework.messages.TrackType.TEXT
      }];
```

Comment: Thanks Leon. Unfortunately the result is the same, do you know how we can remove the tracks that comes from manifest?

Comment: Please file an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190205%20status:open&s=modified_time:desc